# Inno Setup: In the run section, are the Component and Task parameters collective?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm working on an installer using Inno, and I need to choose between two applications the installer should run based on the user's selection of components and/or tasks.

The Logic flow should work like this:
    Component 1 -> application A
    Component 1 with Task 1 -> application B
    Component 2 -> application B
    Component 3 -> application A

All Components are exclusive.

Application A is getting called as I'd expect, but it seems that application B is not getting called at all. Do both the component and the task have to be selected if both are associated with the application? Secondary question: How can I make the task take precedence over the component so that application B gets called if Task 1 is selected, and application A if not?

Answer (score 0):

For searchers, the way I got around this was having duplicate entries in the files and run sections, one tied to the component and another tied to the task.